# Cannot build the official asp.net docker image

Tags: asp.net, docker, dockerfile

I am having trouble building the official ASP.net docker image on a Windows 10 PC :
[microsoft/aspnet - Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnet/)

I am using the [4.6.2 version dockerfile](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-docker/blob/master/4.6.2/Dockerfile) and i get an error when executing the command in line :

```
#download Roslyn nupkg and ngen the compiler binaries
RUN Invoke-WebRequest https://api.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.net.compilers.2.3.1.nupkg -OutFile c:\microsoft.net.compilers.2.3.1.zip ; \  
    Expand-Archive -Path c:\microsoft.net.compilers.2.3.1.zip -DestinationPath c:\RoslynCompilers ; \
    Remove-Item c:\microsoft.net.compilers.2.3.1.zip -Force ; \
    &C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\csc.exe /ExeConfig:c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\csc.exe | \
    &C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\vbc.exe /ExeConfig:c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\vbc.exe  | \
    &C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\VBCSCompiler.exe /ExeConfig:c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\VBCSCompiler.exe | \
    &C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\csc.exe /ExeConfig:c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\csc.exe | \
    &C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\vbc.exe /ExeConfig:c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\vbc.exe | \
    &C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\VBCSCompiler.exe  /ExeConfig:c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\VBCSCompiler.exe ;
```

The error happens when executing **ngen.exe**, and it appears to be some king of digital signature failure :

```
Step 5/8 : RUN Invoke-WebRequest https://api.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.net.compilers.2.3.1.nupkg -OutFile c:\microsoft.net.compilers.2.3.1.zip ;     Expand-Archive -Path c:\microsoft.net.compilers.2.3.1.zip -DestinationPath c:\RoslynCompilers ;     Remove-Item c:\microsoft.net.compilers.2.3.1.zip -Force ;     &C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\csc.exe /ExeConfig:c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\csc.exe |     &C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\vbc.exe /ExeConfig:c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\vbc.exe  |     &C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\VBCSCompiler.exe /ExeConfig:c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\VBCSCompiler.exe |     &C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\csc.exe /ExeConfig:c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\csc.exe |     &C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\vbc.exe /ExeConfig:c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\vbc.exe |     &C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\VBCSCompiler.exe  /ExeConfig:c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\VBCSCompiler.exe ;
 ---> Running in 11f881271a41
Microsoft (R) CLR Native Image Generator - Version 4.6.1586.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070241)
The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; Invoke-WebRequest https://api.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.net.compilers.2.3.1.nupkg -OutFile c:\microsoft.net.compilers.2.3.1.zip ;     Expand-Archive -Path c:\microsoft.net.compilers.2.3.1.zip -DestinationPath c:\RoslynCompilers ;     Remove-Item c:\microsoft.net.compilers.2.3.1.zip -Force ;     &C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\csc.exe /ExeConfig:c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\csc.exe |     &C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\vbc.exe /ExeConfig:c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\vbc.exe  |     &C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\VBCSCompiler.exe /ExeConfig:c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\VBCSCompiler.exe |     &C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\csc.exe /ExeConfig:c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\csc.exe |     &C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\vbc.exe /ExeConfig:c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\vbc.exe |     &C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\VBCSCompiler.exe  /ExeConfig:c:\RoslynCompilers\tools\VBCSCompiler.exe ;' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Any help appreciated.